# Mysql issue with triggers and delimiters from source file

Tags: mysql, triggers, delimiter

I'm getting error if I use source command like the following:

```
mysql> source /home/sqlws/workspace/src.sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER trigg_cust_u   INSERT INTO audit' at line 1ROW
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER trigg_cust_d   INSERT INTO audit' at line 1ROW
```

But if I copy & paste the contents of `/home/sqlws/workspace/src.sql` to mysql-cli, it works like a charm

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS audit_cust;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE audit_cust(audit_ts DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, audit_id BIGINT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT, cust_id bigint(20),PRIMARY KEY (audit_id))ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigg_cust_i;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigg_cust_u;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigg_cust_d;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trigg_cust_i AFTER INSERT ON cust FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO audit_cust(audit_oprn, cust_id)  VALUES('INSERT', NEW.cust_id);
    -> END //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trigg_cust_u AFTER UPDATE ON cust FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO audit_cust(audit_oprn, cust_id) VALUES('UPDATE', NEW.cust_id);
    -> END //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trigg_cust_d AFTER DELETE ON cust FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO audit_cust(audit_oprn, cust_id) VALUES('DELETE', OLD.cust_id);
    -> END //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

**Mysql version:**

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.21    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Host version:**

```
sqlws@tt49:$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Could someone help me figure out the issue

Comment: 'works like a charm' - maybes aye maybes no. Your triggers are all ON cust which isn't defined here.

Comment: I have my cust table.. are you also on ubuntu and same mysql version (may be, it's env-specific) ? So far, I've drilled down the issue to setting delimiter using `source <file>`  more info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49354835/234110)